# Adding content into an element in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a paragraph element and add content to it. Basically i want to let the textContent of a paragraph element be a string.

What i have tried doing is:

```js
var st="Hello";
con=document.getElementById("content");
var pv=document.createElement("p");
con.appendchild(pv);
pv.setAttribute("",st);
```

```html
<span id="content"> </span>
```

What attribute should i use to add in the `setAttribute` function here? I tried using textContent but it's not an attribute. Any other way i can do this?

Comment: User `pv.innerHTML = st;` isntead of setAttribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do with [`elem.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead of `setAttribute`

```js
var st = "Hello";
var con = document.getElementById("content");
var pv = document.createElement("p");
con.appendChild(pv);
pv.innerText= st;
```

```html
<span id="content"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use *innerText* to do this.

```
pv.innerText = "hello"
```

You can set and get the text value of an element using innerText.

More info on innerText can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `innerHTML` which can change not just the text but also the HTML.

```js
let con_txt = document.getElementById("content_text");
let pv_txt = document.createElement("p");
con_txt.appendChild(pv_txt);
pv_txt.innerText = "From innerText";

let con_html = document.getElementById("content_html");
let pv_html = document.createElement("p");
con_html.appendChild(pv_html);
pv_html.innerHTML = "<b>innerHTML also works!</b>"; //You can use HTML tags here
```

```html
<span id="content_text"></span>
<span id="content_html"></span>
```

*Above result in HTML*

```
<span id="content_text">
    <p>From innerText</p>
</span>
<span id="content_html">
    <p><b>innerHTML also works!</b></p>
</span>
```

More info about [`innerHTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)